# WP7 wrap text around image

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have an image with a large amount of text to the right in a textblock control.  How can I get that text to wrap on the right and below the image?

Comment: Are you saying that ur image is inside the textblock??

Comment: No it's not in the textblock, right now both the image and textblock are wrapped inside a stackpanel.  I would like the text to keep wrapping on the right side of the image and eventually wrap below it.

Answer (score 1):

The standard TextBlock and Image controls wouldn't work for you.

I think you'd either:

- have to use HTML inside a WebBrowser (this is potentially very slow and ugly!)
- have to use multiple TextBlock's and you'd have to measure the text in order to implement the wrapping out yourself.

It might be an idea to consider a different layout - is the text really free flowing and needs wrapped around the image? Or can the text be split up into header, caption, body, etc?

Comment: The text is already split up into different pieces.  It's a description of the picture that I wanted to wrap.