# Windows Phone - RichTextBox text wrapping

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I've created control for displaying news. Each new contains text and image. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413240/wp7-wraping-text-around-image) I've found example for RichTextBox:

```
<RichTextBox VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Paragraph
        TextAlignment="Left">
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <InlineUIContainer.Child>
                <Rectangle
                    Width="50"
                    Height="50"
                    Fill="Red" />
            </InlineUIContainer.Child>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <InlineUIContainer>
            <Border>
                <TextBlock
                    Padding="0"
                    Width="370"
                    Margin="0,0,0,-5"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap"
                    Text="First part of text that fits to the right of the image before the other part wraps to">
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </InlineUIContainer>
        <Run
            Text="the next line. This part of the text is already below the image." />
    </Paragraph>
</RichTextBox>
```

But there is trouble: new contains one text block (`<p>...</p>`), and I can't dynamically divide text for 2 textblocks from example. How can I solve my problem? Thank you.
**UPD:** Here's markup of my control:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}" Margin="0,0,0,-100">     
        <TextBlock x:Name="tblNewName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" Height="50" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Mangal"/>
        <Grid Height="105" Width="441">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="97*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="344*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image x:Name="imgThumbnail" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tblNewTeaser" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" Height="50" TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Mangal"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I need wrap text in textblock around image.

Answer (score 1):

What data are you trying to show?
Is this HTML?
Give me an example of news data.

**Update:**
what you need is:

```
 public class NewsItem
    {
        public string ImageUri { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<string> Paragraphs { get; set; }        
    }

<DataTemplate x:Key="newsTemplate">
            <Grid Height="105" Width="441">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="97*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="344*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Paragraphs}"></ListBox>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

<Grid x:Name="colorPlace" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"/>        
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Name="newList" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource newsTemplate}">

</ListBox>
</Grid>
```

and finally:

```
var data = new List<NewsItem>
                       {
                           new NewsItem
                           {
                               ImageUri = String.Empty,
                               Paragraphs = new[]
                                            {
                                                "blablabla",
                                                "blablabla",
                                                "blablabla"
                                            }
                           },
                           new NewsItem
                           {
                               ImageUri = String.Empty,
                               Paragraphs = new[]
                                            {
                                                "blablabla",
                                                "blablabla",
                                                "blablabla"
                                            }
                           }
                       };
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've updated my question and added code of my control. I've already wrote DependencyProperty and all logic for it, but I don't know how to create textwrapping around image.